# Можно ли передавать бизнес-логику через SOAP

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

Есть soap сервис. Я вызываю его из клиентского модуля. Могу ли вызвать его с параметром, POJO-классом, выполняющим бизнес логику(например, сортировку).
И в каком виде в xml будет передан этот параметр

Comment: Что за сортировка? Покажи мне по алфавиту, теперь по количеству? Вряд ли это имеет какое-то отношение к бизнезу. Это всего лишь разное представление. Те же яйца, вид сбоку.

Comment: @Sergey неважно какая сортировка, да и не важно какая там логика. Мне важно понять, POJO класс, в методе которого происходит какое-то вычисление. Можно ли экземпляр этого класса использовать как параметр при вызове удаленного SOAP сервиса. Если да, то в каком виде в xml он будет выглядеть

Comment: Бизнес-логику сервер приложений выполняет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю мой ответ Вам подойдет, из-за схожести Java и C#. Так же в обоих языках имеются лямбда-выражения, в Java они появились чуть позже, в 8-ой версии вроде.

Идея в том, чтобы поведение выразить в виде лямбда-выражения и сериализовать его. Потом передать через SOAP и выполнить десериализацию.

Это работает в C#, для этого я использую эту [библиотеку](https://github.com/esskar/Serialize.Linq)

Answer (score 0):

Через SOAP передаются данные, а не код. Так что передать неизвестный другой стороне алгоритм вы не сможете.

---

Но если алгоритм *известен* другой стороне - то *выбрать* его через SOAP довольно просто.

```
@XmlSeeAlso({AddOperation.class, SubtractOperation.class})
abstract class BaseOperation {
  public abstract int run(int a, int b);
}

class AddOperation extends BaseOperation {
    public int run(int a, int b) {
        return a+b;
    }
}

class SubtractOperation extends BaseOperation {
    public int run(int a, int b) {
        return a-b;
    }
}
```

Теперь если служба принимает в качестве параметра `BaseOperation` - она сможет вызвать у него метод `run` и тем самым использовать алгоритм, выбранный клиентом.

Немаловажен также тот факт, что клиенту в такой схеме не обязательно знать реализации алгоритмов, на его стороне достаточно только имен:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({AddOperation.class, SubtractOperation.class})
abstract class BaseOperation {}

class AddOperation extends BaseOperation {}
class SubtractOperation extends BaseOperation {}
```

---

Также обращаю ваше внимание на тот факт, что перечисления в java тоже могут содержать функции. Этим можно воспользоваться для упрощения структуры данных если у алгоритма никогда не бывает внешних параметров:

```
enum Operation {
    Add {
        public int op(int a, int b) { return a+b; }
    },

    Subtract {
        public int op(int a, int b) { return a-b; }
    };

    public abstract int op(int a, int b);
}
```

Comment: `Operation#op(int a, int b)` стоит объявить абстрактным, он в любом случае переопределяется.

Comment: @Nofate Перечисление не может быть абстрактным, такое вот глупое ограничение.

Comment: enum - не может, а метод - может. вы попробуйте

Comment: @Nofate поверю вам на слово :)